# ValidationRules without binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, validation, validationrules

I want to use the ValidationRules (and it's UI effects) on the textbox without actually binding anything to the textbox.

I want to  use the textbox for some input that doesn't bound to anything but need to validate the input after focus is lost using the ValidationRules.

Can it be done?

```
<TextBox.Text>
   <Binding Path="" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus">
     <Binding.ValidationRules>
        <local:IntegersOnlyValidator/>
     </Binding.ValidationRules>
   </Binding>
 </TextBox.Text>
```

Comment: How do you want to read the input, if you don't want to bind it?

Comment: @svick, Do you mean how would i use the input? I will pass the Text property to some method...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
<TextBox.Text>
    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Text" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus">
      <Binding.ValidationRules>
        <Filters:IntegersOnlyValidator/>
      </Binding.ValidationRules>
   </Binding>
 </TextBox.Text>
```

Comment: It raised StackOverFlowException. It comes more than one time in the validation logic!

Answer (score 2):

Your code-behind should be as independent of the GUI as possible, so I would recommend you to create a property and bind to that. When you want to pass the text to the method, just pass the value of the property.

Comment: but if I have, lets say 10 textboxes , I need to create property for each one? I don't think it's effective.

Comment: @anderi, yes, that's right. The memory used for 10 string properties is 40 bytes (on 32-bit .Net) does that seem like wasting memory to you? Or do you mean something else by “effective”?

Comment: anyway, there is no way to solve it without property binding?

Comment: @anderi, I don't know, but even if there was a way, I think property binding would be a better way.

Comment: @anderi: are these 10 text boxes in a collection? Or are there 10 static text boxes on a form? A usual WPF strategy with any collection is to use some `ItemsControl` and reuse `DataTemplate`s with bindings. If you just have static text boxes, then yeah 1:1 binding. Might take a little up front work, but worth it in the end.

Answer (score 2):

You could bind to just any string, e.g. create one as the source for the binding:

```xml
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib.dll"
```

```xml
  <TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
      <Binding Path=".">
        <Binding.Source>
          <sys:String>Default Text</sys:String>
        </Binding.Source>
        <Binding.ValidationRules>
          <!-- Validation Rules -->
        </Binding.ValidationRules>
      </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
  </TextBox>
```

Comment: sort of a "hack", i am wondering if instead of that I should simply  handle LostFocus event...

Comment: That of course would also be an option, i'd write a behaviour for that though.

Comment: I am new to WPF and unfamiliar with behaviors I am going to read about them right now.